# Orbeon repeats do not support initial values after first iteration

Tags: repeat, orbeon

Using Orbeon to create a form, in a repeat I ran into an issue with setting Initial values.  After the first iteration, the default value does not work.  After some research, I found this to be a common issue, but no resolution.  Need an expression that would keep track of each node that is set and account for any values that are changed from their initial value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a Calculated Value (rather than an Initial Value) which sets the default value if the element is blank, but leaves it alone if it has been completed.

Ie, try something like:

```
if (. = '') then 'default value' else .
```

Comment: Thank you - you pointed me in the right direction.  After some trial and error, I ended up with the following expression:                 if (@Total-Bene > 0 ) then @Total-Bene > 0 else '0' because I used a calculated field, I had to create a false Boolean expression to prevent the field from being Read Only.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have said that you also need to set readonly="false()"